# "They chose no other sort of food, nor did they consider it"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

> *They ate pastries, limber under rigid icing, filled with an indeterminate yellow sweet stuff, not still solid, not yet liquid, like salve that has been left in the sun. **They chose no other sort of food, nor did they consider it.***

Can anyone tell me what the last sentence refers to? Does it mean something like "they didn't eat such things ever again" or..? I'll really appreciate it if you explain to me what this means in the context.

Comment: Please add the source for this quote. Might it be *THE STANDARD OF LIVING*

 by Dorothy Parker

Answer (score 1):

It means they ate only the described pastries, and that was enough for them.

The quotation is from "The Standard of Living", by Dorothy Parker:
[The Tumbrel Diaries](http://angustrumble.blogspot.com/2008/12/standard-of-living.html)

The rest of the quote (including the rest of the sentence in question) shows that the author is describing people who eat miserably unhealthy food, but are still trim and beautiful. In other words, the young.

Comment: Do you mean like "They couldn't even think of any other way of eating." ? or is it something like "they had enough of eating those" because I get the feeling like the first sentence has somewhat negative connotation

Comment: It says that they *didn't* think of any other food. The first sentence may have a negative connotation for someone who eats carefully, but that's not quite clear from the supplied context.

Comment: @UzaWu  I found the source of the quote, and edited my answer. It seems to be pretty negative.